# Accessing record properties with a union of string template types

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use a string template type to represent ids with a meaningful prefix, eg `dta-t-${string}` where `dta-t-` encodes some information about the entity. I have some record types with are indexed by unions of string templates, eg

```js
type ActivityTemplateId = `act-t-${string}`
type FacetTemplateId = `fct-t-${string}`
type DataTemplateId = `dta-t-${string}`

interface Template {
  id: EntityId
  // ...other properties not relevant to the problem
}

interface Store {
  DataTemplate: Record<DataTemplateId, Template>
  FacetTemplate: Record<FacetTemplateId, Template>
  ActivityTemplate: Record<ActivityTemplateId, Template>
}
```

EDIT: I'm accessing the `Store` via the following functions:

```js
type EntityName = 
  | "ActivityTemplate"
  | "FacetTemplate"
  | "DataTemplate"

export const typeofId = (str: string): EntityName | "NO_TYPE" => {
  const prefix = str.slice(0, -36)

  if (prefix === "act-t-") return "ActivityTemplate"
  if (prefix === "fct-t-") return "FacetTemplate"
  if (prefix === "dta-t-") return "DataTemplate"

  else return "NO_TYPE"
}

const get = (store: Store) => (entityId: EntityId) => {
  const type = typeofId(entityId)
  if (type === "NO_TYPE") return null
  const substore = store[type]
  const entity = substore[entityId]
  if (entity) return entity
  else return null
}
```

But when I try to access a record with type <DataTemplateId, Template>, I get an error at the line `const substore = store[type]`, with the following compiler error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'EntityId' can't be used to index type 'Record<`dta-t-${string}`, Template> | Record<`fct-t-${string}`, Template> | Record<`act-t-${string}`, Template>'.
```

I recreated the issue in a TypeScript playground:
[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgN0aAKhAtmANgQ2AgEkATKAXigAN8EBaYegEgG8BnYAJ0QDsBzAL7UAsAChQkKADE6EYJhwEiZSjQBmDJm048Bw8ZOgARQvkV5CJclWqlg+Riw7c+Q0WMPhoAUV5JQVQpxKCgAH1gEFDQQC2VrEPCZOQVsSxVSRIjTBzirMnEvKT8AkAA5fCxoKiyoACJ4JFQMNPi62rrZOHk8onaxUIi6nPNWq37xPiIudTkoXuhWRMRSAC4oEpiCgagAel2oADpjgHtgAAsILigwLhPILiQIdiheM6guCFwIZHx-KGAJwBlxudwARt8sOJBIUxFMrrNulAAMqAz5QJY7EYLdYAJQgcBOXFIAB5sWMMgAaeYUiAAPkSXR6tLxBKJpKZqSU+VI1IWDJ2jWiLW5RFZhOJJKFzVitLIfNpAphnjEEAAHmAicAoITeJwAd4TuoglAABS6da6NwASnWm1AFSqSTqZQA8gB9dAATQACj46pQ6RjErr9bcIOpEGq1LpDuxcIhuqaAAzU+gAZgAbNbYaFEOozeHI9GKKX6nQmEw6taPvIAK5cXj1aUxBb9PMF01FqOUMt1TSV+jV2vABtNzopNvLTvdkt9+yOKs1z6jxv1cmiiATHZfdjQFdj+puz2+-3Q2Gh7X8eRqc1oiDrVFEiA1ihB00QfxbNYbL+BUivkGmKhJeBpSFQRhGmQH5-iAZA5js+ZmkYvZUC6Hren6w4HmuvB1rguAhicerauwdZgpwz4xveADaRgALpESRUCfqUMbkZRnw0ax36MYhnY8aAy71mugkgIku77iJTZ4QR0JAA)

Is there a way for TypeScript to use a string template to index an object without casting to any as is happening? `Entity` in the example should be of type `Template | null`, rather than `any`.

EDIT: I think I may understand the problem a little better after reading jcalz's comments. It seems that what I imagine happening is this:

```
 A -> X
 B -> Y
 C -> Z
```

while what the compiler sees is this:

```
 (A | B | C) -> X
 (A | B | C) -> Y
 (A | B | C) -> Z
```

In other words, the compiler is trying to index **every** variant of the union with every variant of `EntityId`. That would explain why we can get rid of the error by changing

```js
const substore = store[type]
```

to

```js
const substore = store[type] as
    Record<`dta-t-${string}`, Template> &
    Record<`fct-t-${string}`, Template> &
    Record<`act-t-${string}`, Template>
```

Which is like saying:

```
(A | B | C) -> (X & Y & Z)
(A | B | C) -> (X & Y & Z)
(A | B | C) -> (X & Y & Z)
```

Is that an accurate description of the problem?

Comment: Please [edit] to include the [mre] in plain text. Playground links are great but they're not sufficient in themselves.  Anyway, you are running into a problem with correlated unions very much like [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), where the recommended approach is to use generics as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  Unfortunately you'll still need to use type assertions in this approach (what you're calling "casting") because the compiler cannot follow what's going on inside `typeofId()` ...

Comment: ... the fact that `slice()` will grab the relevant prefix, for example.  Anyway, the closest I can get to this is [shown in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N7oQ4N).  I can write that up as an answer, although maybe the cure is worse than the disease in this case.  You could also assert that `substore` is an intersection instead of a union like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9nYMm); this is a mostly harmless lie which lets your code compile.  Does this address your question?  Which, if either, of these approaches, would you like to see in an answer?

Comment: @jcalz Great information, thank you. The first solution is indeed a bit heavy, and I think the intersection method is probably what I'll use. That said, I would be curious to understand the first solution as it seems closer to expressing the problem in terms of the compiler. If you'd be willing to explain a bit more in-depth I'd accept. Either way - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that the compiler can't easily type check what I call *correlated unions*, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  In your case, you have a value `entityId` of [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `KA | KB | KC`, and a value `substore` (evaluated as `store[typeofId(entityId)]`) of union type `Record<KA, T> | Record<KB, T> | Record<KC, T>` (names simplified to protect the weary).  In general, one cannot simply index into a dictionary of type `Record<KA, T> | Record<KB, T> | Record<KC, T>` with a key of type `KA | KB | KC`. After all, what if the dictionary turns out to be of type `Record<KA, T>` but the key is of type `KC`?  And so the compiler complains about `substore[entityId]`.  Because it doesn't know what we know: that the types of `substore` and `entityId` are *correlated* to each other in such a way that the indexing operation is always safe.

---

The easy way to deal with this is just to accept that there are times when you're smarter than the compiler, and this is one of those times, and you will take some of the burden of verifying type safety away from the well-meaning but incompetent thing and onto yourself, by a judicious use of a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) where you either tell the compiler the truth that it doesn't know, or even lie to it in a way that will not lead to runtime problems.  For example:

```
const substore = store[type] as
  Record<DataTemplateId, Template> &
  Record<FacetTemplateId, Template> &
  Record<ActivityTemplateId, Template>; 
// type assertion, a white lie 

const entity = substore[entityId]; // okay
```

Here we're just telling the compiler that `substore` isn't just of type `Record<KA, T> | Record<KB, T> | Record<KC, T>`, but that it's actually of type `Record<KA, T> & Record<KB, T> & Record<KC, T>`.  That is, the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) instead of the union.  It isn't one of those three, it's *all* of them!  This is certainly not true, but luckily we will only be indexing into the one key type it actually does have.  And the compiler is placated because indexing into an intersection *would* be safe.

---

The hard way to deal with this is to try to convey what you're doing to the compiler.  The recommended approach is described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), and it involves refactoring your typings to use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) instead of unions, and where the relationships between the types involve simple [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html).  You can read the GitHub issue for details.

Unfortunately, it's kind of impossible to get the whole way without some type assertions.  The compiler just can't follow what you're doing in `typeofId()` to see that the output will be the particular member of `EntityName` corresponding to the particular member of `EntityId` that came in as input.  The typings for [the `slice()` method of strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) isn't even close to descriptive enough for that.  So inside `typeofId()` we'll have to just tell the compiler what's happening (although hopefully we can at least tell the truth about it).

Here goes:

```
interface EntityNameIdMap {
  ActivityTemplate: ActivityTemplateId,
  FacetTemplate: FacetTemplateId,
  DataTemplate: DataTemplateId
}

const typeofIdMap = {
  "act-t-": "ActivityTemplate",
  "fct-t": "FacetTemplate",
  "dta-t-": "DataTemplate"
} as { [P in keyof EntityNameIdMap as EntityNameIdMap[P]]: P };

export const typeofId = <K extends keyof EntityNameIdMap>(str: EntityNameIdMap[K]): K => {
  const prefix = str.slice(0, -36) as EntityNameIdMap[K] // assert
  const typeofIdMapNarrowed = typeofIdMap as 
    { [P in K]: Record<EntityNameIdMap[P], P> }[K]; // assert
  return typeofIdMapNarrowed[prefix];
}

type Store = { [K in keyof EntityNameIdMap]: 
  Record<EntityNameIdMap[K], Template> 
};

const get = (store: Store) => 
  <K extends keyof EntityNameIdMap>(entityId: EntityNameIdMap[K]) => {
    const type = typeofId(entityId)
    const substore = store[type] // const substore: Store[K]
    const entity: Template | null = substore[entityId]
    if (entity) return entity
    else return null
  }
```

What I've done is rewritten things in terms of operations on a simple helper interface `EntityNameIdMap`, where each `EntityName` member is paired up with its corresponding `EntityId` member.

Then I implement `typeofId` by looking up `prefix` in a `typeofIdMap` object, whose type is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over `EntityNameIdMap`.  I've made `typeofId` generic in `K extends keyof EntityNameIdMap`, and assert a few things to the compiler in order to convince it that if the input is of type `EntityNameIdMap[K]`, then the output is of type `K`.

After this the compiler can follow what I'm doing with no asseritons.  I rewrite `Store` explicitly in terms of `EntityNameIdMap`, so that inside the generic function retuned by `get()`, the compiler can see how `substore` and `entityId` relate.  It sees `substore` as the generic type `Store[K]`, which it now resolves to `Record<EntityNameIdMap[K], Template>` due to the definition of `Store`. And since `entityId` is of the `EntityNameIdMap[K]`, then it knows that `substore[entityId]` is a valid lookup, and results in a value of type `Template` (which I've widened to `Template | null` to keep consistent with your code).

Hooray?

---

So there you go.  Normally in correlated union questions I can refactor so that no type assertions are necessary, and even then, it's not obviously worth the effort to get the added compiler-verified safety.  Type assertions are less safe, but much easier.  In this instance it seems like no content: type assertions win.  But ultimately that decision depends on your use cases.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBJYAXCAnKF7oEsB7YJAbwFgAoJJdATxmQEF8CA3AhgFQjBgA2ITCgAmSALxIABgnQBaBQBIyUdFgLAA5gF9p1WgyZIAYggjpe-ISPFTpAM3yL5KtRu16DdRsgAiwiBWgsIQYpIyouggLm7qmrr6VN5GyACiGFz04RLetAA+SKyEnDx8IbZ5SIVmiJblNmGiVYUB0cGNYtQpvkgZhAwAcuDIuTS01UgARMUcWR2hUy3TtRYLmEvjBdNtQQ2L3eOamFgO5kjryJRbSASiAFx9mQxdNwD0b0gAdD9E6AAW2CQMCwRCYWEI0CQwD+SCwEAEEHYIAwdCIdEBwNBACNEWBvDpDrRjtgzogkABldBEeHkKq7S6PABKeBpogAPAz9rYADQXbkQAB8VVW9WsoWZrKwHNFlzEfMuwpus1K9EZSBZ8DZ7JV8wF8v54swStohOS4wgAA8YDT0EgtcA1D4mEQHDkkAAKdyPdwJACUj36WWGkEmU0GAHkAPrcACaAAU0lNJIK6TcHU6QRAHARLRF3F8oAICIgPQAGPnyADMADY-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-5YIGL223LDsBkgevgV9XuOnaB7sVghbFqWFZINWdaSxHb1J3xm0CbgEImVnPtR8MWCggA7hAeUo77EsCXJnPc-rDuSlbHLl1H8t8vGLv2zxhlINXUC1+gVR+aQXdNyALdEO3oicQes-3eMqE-naUj-iBQEcYhVT+0ggdQSHBuC+HCeR7L0cufZq2vxXMAz4hGdaCoSIlIdeohP59T7JtYBvhHg6zkoxKyHF2IgW4r4We89PiIJYhxS+qCHYIO9p5egjwlqFACgISyODUHEIcnJZyxC3IXlIMQuSPlHz+VovRG4IVzQ6CAA)

Comment: Super clear, thank you! Is this the sort of problem some languages address via pattern matching? Rather than encoding the correlation between the unions in a type mapping, pattern matching would just "handle every case"? In my usage, it would be nice if I could "pattern match" on the result of `typeofId`: then inside each branch of the pattern, I could be sure what type I'm working with. I suppose I can do this - I just have to write a type assertion, which should be safe if it's a truly exhaustive pattern match. The safety just wouldn't be guaranteed by the compiler.